# Why Spring batch JobParameters using LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, spring, hashmap, spring-batch, linkedhashmap

Compared to `HashMap`, `LinkedHashMap` guarantees input order.

In Spring Batch, I think `HashMap` is enough to save `JobParameter`, but I don't know why `JobParameters` used `LinkedHashMap`. What do you think about this?

Below are some of the implementations of `JobParameters`. [Github Link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/fe40370f398f8ba89b372d594d67c8051d735a5c/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/JobParameters.java#L55)

```java
public class JobParameters implements Serializable {

    private final Map<String,JobParameter> parameters;

    public JobParameters() {
        this.parameters = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    }

    public JobParameters(Map<String,JobParameter> parameters) {
        this.parameters = new LinkedHashMap<>(parameters);
    }

    // ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no ordering between job parameters. The usage of a linked hash map is not justified in my opinion.

You can open an issue with a link to this SO thread and we will consider changing that in Spring Batch.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/4179

I opened an issue. Thank you for your opinion.